# display 3d pictures on website

Tags: 3d

So this might be a hard question to answer considering the few results I have found on the net. 
I take 3d pictures with my own camera and they are separated into 2 files; left side and right side. I would like to display it on my picture gallery online. I figured the new computers can display 3d images like 3d tv's do with the glasses I assume. Maybe I am completely wrong. Is there a proper way to display or combine the 2 files into one and look 3d for people with those capabilities.  I can not do any cross eyed techniques. If not that is ok.

Other question is: how do I let people download them. In a zip file I guess or is there a way a user can right click and save both images to computer at once? Does anybody know if can?  I would love to know. Thanks.

To be more specific . 1 file is a jpeg and the other is an .mpo file.

Comment: Possibly a [JPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_Stereo#JPEG_Stereoscopic) file would work.

Comment: thanks.. So ok I'm not quite sure I understand yet. Would I change the extention to jps. Would I upload the mpo file or JPEG. Can I just put it in a img tag?